# Can I use KSoap2 to send a static XML file as a request

Tags: java, android, xml, ksoap2

I am using KSoap2 to try to build the XML file request below.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:_5="www.444.com">

<soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
  <_5:GetStaff>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <_5:Request>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <_5:SourceCredentials>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <_5:SourceName>sourcename</_5:SourceName>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <_5:Password>password=</_5:Password>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <_5:SiteIDs>
              <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
              <_5:int>1111</_5:int>
           </_5:SiteIDs>
              </_5:SourceCredentials>
          </_5:Request>
       </_5:GetStaff>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I've attempted to take this and generate the following code but it seems the child elements are causing me problems. I'm new to Ksoap2 and can't find a clear solution to structuring.

```
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        request.addProperty("SourceName", "sourcename");
        request.addProperty("Password", "password=");
        request.addProperty("int", "1111");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope( SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE htse = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try{
            htse.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive resultString = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

           ret = resultString.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

How would i used KSoap2 to build the tree in order for the child elements to be accessed correctly. The api doesn't respond correctly without this structure.

Is there a way to send this xml file out of maybe an xml resource directly?

or is there another way?

UPDATE: tried to make classes for complex elements

```
import org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;

import java.util.Hashtable;

/**
* Created by randypfohl on 7/15/15.
*/
public class SourceCredentials implements KvmSerializable {

//Xml variables
private String sourceName;
private String password;
private SiteIDs site;

public SourceCredentials() {
}

public void setSourceName(String sourceName) {
    this.sourceName = sourceName;
}

public String getSourceName() {
    return this.sourceName;
}

public void  setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return this.password;
}

public void setSiteIDs(SiteIDs site) {
    this.site = site;
}

@Override
public Object getProperty(int index) {

    Object toreturn = null;

    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            toreturn = this.sourceName;
        case 1:
            toreturn = this.password;
        case 2:
            toreturn = this.site;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return toreturn;
}

    @Override
    public int getPropertyCount () {
        return 3;
    }


        @Override
        public void setProperty ( int index, Object value){
            switch (index) {
                case 0:
                    this.sourceName = value.toString();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    this.password = value.toString();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    site.setProperty(0, value);
                    break;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void getPropertyInfo ( int index, Hashtable hashtable, PropertyInfo propertyInfo){
        switch (index) {
            case 0:
                propertyInfo.name = "SourceName";
                propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                break;
            case 1:
                propertyInfo.name = "Password";
                propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                break;
            case 2:
                propertyInfo.name = "SiteIDs";
                propertyInfo.type = SiteIDs.class;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getInnerText () {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setInnerText (String s){

    }
}
```

and this is the siteids class.

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Vector;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.KvmSerializable;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;

public class SiteIDs extends Vector<Integer> implements KvmSerializable {

@Override
public Object getProperty(int arg0) {
    return this.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public String getInnerText () {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void setInnerText (String s){

}

@Override
public int getPropertyCount() {
    return 1;
}

@Override
   public void getPropertyInfo(int arg0, Hashtable arg1, PropertyInfo arg2) {
    arg2.name = "int";
    arg2.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
}

@Override
public void setProperty(int arg0, Object arg1) {
    this.add(Integer.valueOf(arg1.toString()));
}
}
```

this is the code that i created.

/*  String ret ="fail";

```
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        SourceCredentials sourceCredentials = new SourceCredentials();
        sourceCredentials.setProperty(0, "name");
        sourceCredentials.setProperty(1, "password");

        SiteIDs siteIDS = new SiteIDs();
        siteIDS.setProperty(0, "1100");
        sourceCredentials.setSiteIDs(siteIDS);

        request.addProperty("SourceCredentials", sourceCredentials);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope( SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, SourceCredentials.class.getSimpleName(), SourceCredentials.class);
        envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, SiteIDs.class.getSimpleName(), SiteIDs.class);

        try{
            HttpTransportSE htse = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            htse.debug = true;
            htse.setXmlVersionTag("<!--?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding= \"UTF-8\" ?-->");
            htse.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapPrimitive resultString = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

           ret = resultString.toString();
            System.out.println(ret);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return ret;
```

I can't figure it out. i seem to always get a strange error.

```
 SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@b1eb5d78
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create serializable objects and pass them to the SOAP object.

```
public class SourceCredentials implements KvmSerializable {

    //Xml variables
    private String sourceName;
    private String password;
    private SiteIDs siteIDs;


    public SourceCredentials(){
    }

    public setSourceName(String sourceName){
        this.sourceName = sourceName;
    }

    public String getSourceName(){
        return this.sourceName;
    }

    public setPassword(String password){
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getPassword(){
        return this.password;
    }

    public setSiteIDs(SiteIDs siteIDs){
        this.siteIDs = siteIDs;
    }

    public getSiteIDs(){
        return this.siteIDs;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(int index) {

        switch(index){
            case 0:
                return this.sourceName;
            case 1:
                return this.password;
            case 2:
                return this.siteIDs;
            default:
                break
    }

    @Override
    public int getPropertyCount() {
        return 3;


    @Override
    public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
        switch(index){
            case 0:
                this.sourceName = value.toString();
                break;
            case 1:
                this.password = value.toString();
                break;
            case 2:
                this.siteIDs = (SiteIDs) value;                    
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable hashtable, PropertyInfo propertyInfo) {
        switch (index){
            case 0:
                propertyInfo.name = "SourceName";
                propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                break;
            case 1:
                propertyInfo.name = "Password";
                propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                break;
            case 2:
                propertyInfo.name = "SiteIDs";
                propertyInfo.type = PropertyInfo.OBJECT_CLASS;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getInnerText() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setInnerText(String s) {

    }
```

And you do the same with SiteIds

Then you pass the Soap object.

**EDIT**

**You try this?**

```
SourceCredentials sourceCredentials = new SourceCredentials();

//Create SiteIDs KvmSerializable object
SiteIDs siteIDS = new SiteIDS();
siteIDS.setInt(1111)

//Setters
sourceCredentials.setSourceName("sourcename");
sourceCredentials.setPassword("password=");
sourceCredentials.setSiteIDS(siteIDS);


request.addProperty("SourceCredentials", sourceCredentials);
```

**EDIT 2**

Try this

**SiteIDS.java**

```
public class SiteIDs implements KvmSerializable {

    private List<Integer> Int; //change name of variable, int it's a reserved name

    public SiteIDs() {
    }

    public List<Integer> getInt() {
        return Int;
    }

    public void setInt(List<Integer> anInt) {
        Int = anInt;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(int i) {
        switch (i){
            case 0:
                return Int;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPropertyCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void setProperty(int i, Object value) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                this.Int = (List<Integer>) value;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void getPropertyInfo(int i, Hashtable hashtable, PropertyInfo propertyInfo) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                propertyInfo.name = "int";
                propertyInfo.type = List.class;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getInnerText() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setInnerText(String s) {

    }
```

And this:

```
SourceCredentials sourceCredentials = new SourceCredentials();

    //Create SiteIDs KvmSerializable object
      SiteIDs siteIDS = new SiteIDS();
      List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
      ints.add(1111); //add one o more ints
      siteIDS.setInts(ints);
   //Setters
      sourceCredentials.setSourceName("sourcename");
      sourceCredentials.setPassword("password=");
      sourceCredentials.setSiteIDS(siteIDS);


      request.addProperty("SourceCredentials", sourceCredentials);
```

Comment: I followed this method and it seems like a great option however i'm getting the same issue. it's saying there is a null value included. Could it be from the integer objects inside of the siteIDs section? I tried to alt the code to an array to manage it but i got a not serializable error. :/

Comment: You put me on the right track. I believe that i'll get it soon. Once completed i'll update my answer and give you credit. thanks man.

Comment: If you still do not get it, show me the SiteIDS object  to help better.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I'm stuck on this issue with out current set up. This is the request stream.     : 

<SourceName i:type="d:int">1100</SourceName><Password i:type="d:int">1100</Password><SiteIDs i:type="d:int">1100</SiteIDs></SourceCredentials></GetStaff></v:Body></v:Envelope>        I'ts not supposed to have type int nor those values inside.

Comment: Have the published code on github? to see it? Or to help, edit your question by adding more information.

Comment: I figured it out! you win! Thank you so much!